# My Tinder bot won't stop autoswiping right

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I want to avoid bot detection and my random stuff isn't working. Actually it's not hitting dislike at all. Xpaths are all right. What am I doing wrong here?

```
def auto_swipe(self):
    while True:
        sleep_time = random.randrange(1, 3)
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
        try:
            rand1 = random.randrange(0,100)
            if rand1 < random.randrange(70,80):
                self.like()
            else:
                self.dislike()
        except Exception:
            try:
                self.close_popup()
            except Exception:
                self.close_match()
```

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to use `random` is as follows. Assuming you'd like something to happen 75% of the time, you'll write the following:

```
if random.random() < 0.75:
   # do something
```

Comment: I can't upvote, but that was it. Thanks!

Comment: solution in context

try:
                rand = random()
                if rand < .78:
                    self.like()
                else:
                    self.dislike()